# Chrome 18 3d translate performance

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, requestanimationframe, translate3d

Just updated Chrome to 18.0.1025.142 from 17 on a Mac running 10.7.1 and it's killed the performance of our site. We've been using translate3d where available to move a large number of items around the screen. I'm animating with requestAnimationFrame. In 17 we were getting framerates upwards of 50fps. Now lucky to get 15fps. It's really bad.

Has hardware acceleration been turned off by default? Anyone else noticed any problems like this? I've noticed the font rendering has been improved and is now on a par with Safari (which runs the site beautifully) maybe this change has had an effect on general rendering performance?

I'm afraid I can't share the link due to an NDA. But any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

As far as I can tell it IS still GPU accelerated but the performance is really bad, other people have reported similar things. The Chromium builds of v19 seem to be back to the old quality of performance.

There used to be a flag when launching chrome --show-composited-layer-borders which would put red borders around gpu accelerated elements. This option now seems to have been added to chrome://flags/ but it paints green borders around layers and doesn't seem to distinguish gpu elements any more. Does anyone know of an option to show if elements are being rendered by the gpu?

chrome://gpu/ says that everything is being hardware accelerated...

Comment: I've filed a bug report on Chromium here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121077&thanks=121077&ts=1333109384

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce the problem with fresh code in a new web page.  This will greatly help both your SO question and bug report.

Browsers regularly tweak whether hardware acceleration is used based on whether your graphics card and driver version is supported.  Updating your graphics card driver may fix the problem for *you*, but maybe not everyone else.  (This tool I wrote might help: [graphics driver updater](http://www.scirra.com/blog/73/introducing-the-graphics-driver-updater-utility))

In fact it's a bad idea for your website to depend on hardware acceleration, because a significant fraction of users have crappy unsupported hardware and/or out of date drivers which are blacklisted to stop the user's computer crashing while they browse the web.  They'll get crappy, un-accelerated framerates too, in any version of Chrome.

So IMO the real problem is your website depends on hardware acceleration which not everyone has, and you just noticed because Google blacklisted your setup in Chrome 18.

Comment: I will try to reproduce in a sharable URL, but I simply don't have time right now. IF it is a hardware acceleration issue, it is corrected in Chromium Mac dev build 121128 (19.0.1036.0). This is true across all of our machines (Mac or Windows). I agree relying on hardware acceleration is a bad idea, we're only using translate3d if supported, otherwise left and top positioning. Annoyingly, left and top positioning produces smoother animation than buggy translate3d, but working translated3d significantly outperforms both. We can only test if translate3d is available NOT if it's working properly.